# Отслеживание сетевой активности при отладке

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть ли в Android Studio возможность в режиме отладки отследить, что устройство отправляет по сети?

Comment: Можете искать по запросу "сниффер".

Comment: если речь идет о вашем приложении с целью отладки, то можете попробовать Stetho - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/stetho.php

Comment: @ermak0ff, речь идёт именно о том приложении, которое я разрабатываю. Спасибо. Попробую.